# What is the advantage of neutral atom quantum network advantage?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, network

I'm interested in quantum network system using neutral atom for my interest of atomic physics.

But I'm curious about what the advantage of the neutral-atom-based quantum network instead of other platforms such as NV center, quantum  dot, something like that.

Please help me out.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I know a little bit about these platforms as used for quantum computing. This may be close to what you're asking, but maybe not.

To my understanding, the platforms you mention all compete with each other and it's not really clear whether one has some decisive advantage over the others. The relevant things are the coherence times (i.e. how long it takes for the system to lose information due to noise), fidelity of the gates (i.e. how precisely you can manipulate the system), and maybe some other factors.

The neutral atoms (and, I believe, ions) are manipulated by optical tweezers. I suppose that it gives the advantage that you can easily place the atoms in a line to a good precision.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you mean "the cavity" as "quantum well" or something else?